# iphone application development Newbie - connecting webapp server to iphone application server

Tags: ios, wordpress, web-applications, zend-server

I am trying to develop an iPhone application for a dating website which is hosted on wordpress backed by zend server.

My question is if it is possible to connect my iphone application to the same server as the website or would it require another server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Anything is possible, you'll probably have to scale outward from the sound of it.  What I would suggest is first adapting your site with HTML5 to make a really "mobile friendly" version of what you already have.  I like using Brandoo wordpress because it allows me to do all of my databasing on my SQL server so it's easy.